# Ajax POST request to PHP email validator - how to obtain email input value?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation, virtuemart

I´m working on creating an Ajax email validation on the checkout page of my Joomla/Virtuemart webshop.

This email validator must check to see if the typed in email address already exists in the database and show a live message.

I have almost completed this script but it seems that the POST-data sent by the Ajax code is not transferred correctly to my PHP-script.

Here is my jQuery script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#confirmbtn_button').attr('disabled','');
    var emailok = false;
    var myForm = jQuery("#adminForm"), email = jQuery("#email_field"), emailInfo = jQuery("#emailInfo");
        var emaildata = jQuery('#email_field').val();

    //send ajax request to check email
    email.blur(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {fmail:emaildata},
            url: "/CustomCodes/js/check.php",
            beforeSend: function(){
                emailInfo.html("<font color='blue'>Undersøger Email...</font>");
            },
            success: function(data){
                if(data == "invalid")
                {
                    emailok = false;
                    emailInfo.html("<font color='red'>Ugyldig Email</font>");
                }
                else if(data != "0")
                {
                    emailok = false;
                    emailInfo.html("<font color='red'>Email Eksisterer Allerede..</font>");
                }
                else
                {
                    emailok = true;
                    emailInfo.html("<font color='green'>Email OK</font>");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And this is my PHP validation script:

```
    <?php
$email = $_POST['fmail'];

//data connection file
//require "config.php";
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] );

require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'factory.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');

$ftpSERVERURL = JPATH_BASE;
$MainsiteURL = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

// Load configuration
$conf =& JFactory::getConfig();
require_once( JPATH_BASE .DS.'configuration.php' );
$config = new JConfig();
$conf->loadObject($config);

$host = $conf->getValue('config.host');
$user = $conf->getValue('config.user');
$password = $conf->getValue('config.password');
$database = $conf->getValue('config.db');

 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db($database) or die(mysql_error()); 


if(eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email))
{
        $sql = "select * from jos_users where email='$email'";
        $rsd = mysql_query($sql);
        $msg = mysql_num_rows($rsd); //returns 0 if not already exist
}
else
{
        $msg = "invalid";
}
echo $msg;
?>
```

So basically I need to make sure that I retrieve the email-value correctly, using a code similar to this in the PHP script:

$email = $_POST['fmail'];

The HTML markup of the email input field in the form is like this:

```
<input onfocus="inputclear(this)" autocomplete="off" type="text" id="email_field" name="email" size="30" value="" class="required" maxlength="100" aria-required="true" required="required" aria-invalid="false">
```

I hope someone can help me with this.
It seems like a very small problem, but I´m very much a noob when it comes to Ajax and jQuery

Comment: What is the error/issue?
Also, emaildata = jQuery('#email_field').val(); should be within the blur function, before ajax call

Comment: The specific problem is that I can´t figure out how to correctly transmit the value of the email input field (ID "email_field") via POST to the PHP script "check.php".

Comment: So are you saying that if I add "emaildata = jQuery('#email_field').val();" just after "email.blur(function(){" then "data: {fmail:emaildata}" will transmit the email input via POST so I can call the value with "$email = $_POST['fmail'];" in the PHP script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Dru for pointing me in the right direction I figured out how to change my jQuery code so that it works.
Here is the updated jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    //jQuery('#confirmbtn_button').attr('disabled','');
    var emailok = false;
    var myForm = jQuery("#adminForm"), email = jQuery("#email_field"), emailInfo = jQuery("#emailInfo");

    //send ajax request to check email
    email.blur(function(){
    var emaildata = jQuery('#email_field').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {fmail:emaildata},
            url: "/CustomCodes/js/check.php",
            beforeSend: function(){
                emailInfo.html("");
            },
            success: function(data){

                if(data == "invalid")
                {
                    emailok = false;
                    emailInfo.html('<div class="invalid" style="width: 292px;color: #F00;position: relative;top: -12px;margin-bottom: -14px;left: 10px;">Den indtastede Email: "'+ emaildata + '" - er ugyldig!!!</div>');
                    jQuery('#email_field').val('');
                }

                else if(data != "0")
                {
                    emailok = false;
                    emailInfo.html("<div class='alreadyexist' style='width: 292px;color: #F00;position: relative;top: -12px;margin-bottom: -14px;left: 10px;'>Email: "+ emaildata + ", findes allerede i systemet. Log ind ovenfor.</div>");
                    jQuery('#email_field').val('');
                }
                /*
                else
                {
                    emailok = true;
                    emailInfo.html("<font color='green'>Email OK.</font>");
                }
                */
            }
        });
    });
});
```

As you can see I simply had to move "var emaildata = jQuery('#email_field').val();" so that it is placed right after "email.blur(function(){" and now I can retrieve the data in the PHP script (check.php) by calling "$email = $_POST['fmail'];"